# Black login screen after decryption splash screen on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, intel-graphics, login-screen

I got a thumb drive with Ubuntu on it from a friend. It was working fine except for the touchpad and in the process of trying to fix the touchpad I messed something up. Now after I type in the password on the decryption splash screen it brings me to a black screen instead of the normal login screen.
The last thing I did was modify the grub file.
Replaced
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
with

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"

I since removed the i8042.reset through recovery mode but that didn't work.
I have been trying to Google the issue but haven't found anything.

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo update-grub` to transfer the modification to `grub.cfg`?

Comment: Yes... No luck.

Comment: Are there files with valuable data in the thumb drive? In that case you need to copy those files, when booted from some other drive. After that you can create a fresh Ubuntu system in your thumb drive.